PHONE_CODE_EXPIRED (caused by auth.SignIn) Error during authorization using node package 'telegram'
when i put apiId , apiHash , mobile nummber through the bot then i received phone_code of my telegram app, when i enter phone_code in bot then i received

code:
            const author = async () => {
                console.log("Loading interactive example...");
                const client = new TelegramClient(stringSession, parseInt(API_ID), API_HASH, {
                    connectionRetries: 5,
                });
                await client.start({
                    phoneNumber: async () => {
                        await bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'Please enter phoneNumber.');
                        return new Promise((resolve) => {
                            bot.onText(/^\+[0-9]+$/, async (msg) => { // Modify the regex pattern to allow '+' and digits
                                const phoneNumbers = msg.text;
                                resolve(phoneNumbers);
                            });
                        });
                    },
                    password: async () => {
                        await bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'Please Enter Password ');
                        return new Promise((resolve) => {
                          bot.onText(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/, async (msg) => { // Modify the regex pattern to allow '+' and digits
                            const passwords = msg.text;
                            resolve(passwords);
                            await bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'Please Enter Code ');
                            });
                        });
                    },
                    phoneCode: async () => {
                      await bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'Please Enter Phone Code ');
                      return new Promise((resolve) => {
                          bot.onText(/^[0-9]+$/, async (msg) => { // Modify the regex pattern to allow digits
                              const phoneCodes = msg.text;
                              resolve(phoneCodes);
                          });
                      });
                  },
                      onError: (err) => console.log(err),
                      });
                console.log("You should now be connected.");
                const sessionString = client.session.save(); // Save this string to avoid logging in again
                console.log(sessionString);
                await bot.sendMessage(chatId, `Here is your session string: ${sessionString}`);
            };

but intresting thing is when i only some changes in phoneCode key in code :
  phoneCode: async () =>
      await input.text("Please enter the code you received: "),

and enter phoneCode in terminal then i received session without any error.
i try to also put phoneCode using bot not to go to terminal and paste phone_code manually and save session.

So basically Telegram watches if you are trying to send your code to somebody else, even to your bot.
If you do that, it expires immediately.
You simply can hide the real code, like instead of typing the real one like: 123456 you can provide something like 1a2a3a4a5a6 and remove letters on your backed resulting it into original 123456. But you didn't type exact 123456 inside telegram, so it will be working.
I did my own algo that just increases every number.
So in my case I input 012345 to get 123456 code.

Extremely helpful. I was struggling with this issue for over a year now! Turns out it's this simple. Your solution with passing the code in an "obfuscated" form (I've used letters) and "deobfuscating" it on the server side solved my login issue completely!

write confirm code with spaces like:
1 2 3 4 5
and put the code without spaces (use .trim() method) into resolve
